# fs.readFile no me da un formato correcto para pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf, nodejs

Estoy intentando cargar un `pdf` en una nueva pestaña del navegador pasándolo por `res.send` para que el archivo siga siendo privado y no accesible a no ser que el usuario tenga los permisos necesarios.
El problema está en que cuando se abre el archivo `pdf` en el navegador, no aparece el contenido, las hojas aparecen en blanco.

El código en node.js es:

```
FilesController.prototype.showPdfInBrowser = function (req, res) {
var filePath = "My url"

fs.readFile(filePath , function (err,data){
    res.send(data);
});
};
```

Y el de AngularJS (Angular 1):

```
$scope.showPdfInBrowser = function (log) {
            $http.get(log.url)
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileUrl);
                })
        };
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés

Comment: ya está traducida

Comment: el título faltaría.

Comment: @Alan, no se a que te refieres con el título. Como aclaración es la primera vez que publico algo en stack overflow. Gracias

Comment: puedes hacer un console.log(data) del backend?

Comment: @Fzurita no te preocupes solo tratamos de ayudarte a mejorar la publicación, ya está traducido el título. ! abrazo.

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara , lo que da es como un buffer:       `<Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 54 79 70 65 2f 45 6d 62 65 64 64 65 64 46 69 6c 65 2f 53 75 62 74 79 70 ... >
`

Comment: The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the contents of the file.

If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

De la página de node, retorna un buffer al no especificar un formato. Prueba a ponerle 'utf-8' entre filepath y function.

Answer (score 1):

Al final ya solucioné el problema. Simplemente había que poner cuál era el tipo de datos que iba a recibir la petición en AngularJS (Angular 1).

Haciendo referencia al ejemplo que puse al publicar la pregunta, en la parte de AngularJS habría que poner lo siguiente:

```
$scope.showPdfInBrowser = function (log) {
    $http.get(log.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })   // <----- tipo de datos
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var file = new Blob([data.data], {type:'application/pdf'});
            var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileUrl);
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro pero creo que estas usando express, si es asi puedes usar `res.sendFile` o `res.sendfile` (dependiendo de la version que estes usando)

Answer (score 0):

por si quieres dar una vista mas detallada puedes usar PDF.js , solo le tendrias que agregar una linea de codigo asi :

```
$scope.showPdfInBrowser = function (log) {
$http.get(log.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })   // <----- tipo de datos
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var file = new Blob([data.data], {type:'application/pdf'});
        var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var viewerUrl = '/Scripts/PDF.js/web/viewer.html?file=' + encodeURIComponent(fileUrl);
        window.open(viewerUrl);
    })
};
```

y el resultado seria algo asi https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html. Saludos